# Wordpress All pages but home simply read “hello”

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

My WordPress weirdly stopped working recently... The home page loads as intended but every page further in simply reads "hello"

I checked template files and event tried to deliberately reach a 404 page but even then all i see is hello..

Permalink and Read settings were all resaved and seem to be in order but the problem persists.

I tried to re-upload all theme files. nothing... I dont think this has anything to do with the childtheme. could have something to do with `twentythirteen` but i havent changed anything.

```
    <html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>
```

anything helps...

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the `htaccess` file? Or looking (via cPanel File Manager or your favorite FTP program) for files that have been changed?

And perhaps going to the Admin/Update panel and reinstalling WP 4.8.